# Don't get the content copied of a sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I have this code:

```
connect-pnponline -url xxxxx -Credential $credential
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List "FirstList" -Id "1" -Fields "Description" <=====NOT GOOD
Set-PnPListItem -List "SecondList" -Identity "78" -Values @{"Description"=$item} -SystemUpdate
```

I can not get the content of the first row of the column Description of the first list.

P.

Comment: Do you receive any results if you just run 'Get-PnPListItem -List "FirstList" -Id "1" ' ?

Comment: Try $item = (Get-PnPListItem -List "FirstList" -Id "1").fieldValues and then Set-PnPListItem -List "SecondList" -Identity "78" -Values @{"Description"=$($item.Description)} -SystemUpdate

Comment: It needs to get a value of the first row of the column "Description"

Comment: Yes, and it would. Check $item.Description or just $item to see the properties retrieved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below command:

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "SecondList" -Identity "78" -Values @{"Description"=$item["Description"]} -SystemUpdate
```

Comment: The problem is retreiving the data

Comment: connect-pnponline -url xxxxx -Credential $credential
$item = Get-PnPListItem -List "TestLogging" -Id "1" -Fields "Description"
Set-PnPListItem -List "Logging" -Identity "72" -Values @{"Description"="​​$item"} -SystemUpdate

Comment: IT WORKS :) Thank you. Gr. P